# how to stop javascript for loop/ function on hover

Tags: javascript, css

It seems very simple question but i could not find its answer from exiting question-answer, or I may not be able to understand it. Actually I am changing the images like a slider with javascript and css, it is very simple script. - But one thing I want, when we hover on the image, the image changing/ slider should stop and when we remove mouse pointer from it, then it should start changing again like before. Following is my CSS, html and java I have used to create this very simple image changing/ slider code.

CSS:

`.myRupSlides {display:none;}`

And HTML is:

```
<img class="myRupSlides" src="admgs/image-1.jpg" alt="Image-1">
<img class="myRupSlides" src="admgs/image-2.jpg" alt="Image-2">
<img class="myRupSlides" src="admgs/image-3.jpg" alt="Image-3">
```

And the javascript code is :

```
     <script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myRupSlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>
```

Every thing is working very fine, the image changes every 4 seconds, but I want if we hover the mouse pointer on the image, the image changing should stop and the same image stays visible till the time we keep mouse pointer on image block. And it should start changing like before when we remove mouse pointer from the image.
I am not able to achieve this - please help me how to do.... sorry for my poor English and grammar and thank in advance for solution and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because of the SetTimeout, it's going to execute anyway when 4 secs has passed

An approach can be to remove the timeout setting it to a global variable and handle it with the mouse events

```
//Set the timeout inside a global variable 
 myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
```

then

```
//Clear timeout on mouse over
$('#silder').on('mouseenter',function(){
     clearTimeout(myTimeout); 
});

//start timeout again when mouse leaves
$('#silder').on('mouseleave',function(){
     myTimeout = setTimeout(carousel, 4000); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian Gonzalez.. its is working fine, I got what I want.. thanks dude.